# Does every complete Boolean Algebra that is a proper class have a anti-chain that is a proper class?

Tags: set-theory, boolean-algebra

We work in Kelley-Morse class theory and assume global choice. Let B be a complete Boolean algebra that is a proper class (B is complete in the sense that every subclass of it has a minimal upper bound). Let's assume that B is NOT atomic. Do we know that B must have an anti-chain that is also a proper class?

I was trying to show that B has a maximal chain that is a proper class, which would produce an anti-chain that is a proper class. But I'm not clear if a maximal chain in B has to be a proper class.

Comment: Could you please add your own thoughts on it? I mean what you have thought so far, and please be a little more clear.

Comment: I added the background theory. Is it better now?

Comment: It might help to consider simpler versions first. E.g. is there an infinite complete Boolean algebra with only finite antichains?

Comment: Thinking in ZFC with an inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$, consider the regular open algebra for adding $\kappa$ Cohen reals. That has only countable antichains, but its usual definition would make it a collection of subsets of $\kappa$. Thanks to the ccc, though, it has cardinality only $\kappa$, so there should be a copy of it that's a subset of $\kappa$. That seems to put it into the range of Kelley-Morse class theory, interpreted with sets (classes) being everything of rank $<(\leq)\,\kappa$.